# Protegendo o formulário contra invasão

Tags: php

qual a maneira eficaz de proteger o formulário contra invasão?

Utilizo o seguinte código para filtrar alguns tipos de invasão:

```
 function anti_injection($sql)
{
 $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$sql);
 $sql = trim($sql);
 $sql = strip_tags($sql);
 $sql = addslashes($sql);
 return $sql;
}

$imvloginanti = anti_injection($imvlogin);
$imvsenhaanti = anti_injection($imvsenha);
```

De que forma posso tornar a segurança mais eficaz?

Comment: Usando Prepared Statement do PDO.

Comment: Ou melhor ainda, se o DB for MySQL, use mysqli com prepared statements + binding. Os bindings do mysqli são reais e enviados para o servidor, e não simulados no cliente com concatenação de strings como o PDO faz.

Comment: Não é por nada não, mas essa função aí da pergunta é o tipo da coisa de quem não faz a mínima idéia do que está fazendo. Não sei de onde vc tirou, mas tome cuidado com outras orientações da mesma fonte.

Comment: Update: achei essa função no [phpfreaks.com](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/197036-trying-to-prevent-sql-injection-grendel/), e realmente o autor do post comentou que não entende de segurança. Aí ele foi trocando por versões menos piores, e até passou perto de uma boa. Mas como foi em 2010, nao era mysqli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o @Marco falou, usando o prepared statement do PDO

**Exemplo:**

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.seudominio.com.br;dbname=baseDeDados", "Usuario", "Senha");

$statement = $pdo->prepare("Insert into tabela values(
                            :valor1,
                            :valor2,
                            :valor3)");

$statement->bindParam(':valor1', $SUA_VAR_VALOR_1);
$statement->bindParam(':valor2', $SUA_VAR_VALOR_3);
$statement->bindParam(':valor3', $SUA_VAR_VALOR_2);
$statement->execute();
```